# Transformar string em maiúsculo antes do traço

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como transformar string em maiúsculo antes de um traço ( - ) conforme for digitando, usando jQuery/JavaScript?

Exemplo de texto: "ab- Olá mundo cx- Tudo bem?"

Saída: `AB- Olá mundo CX- Tudo bem?`

```
//
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
   $(this).val( ? );
});
```

Comment: como marcar o status desta publicação como RESOLVIDO?

Answer (score 2):

Tem como fazer assim:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
   var mystr = $(this).val();
   var myarr = mystr.split("-");
   var myvar = myarr[0].toUpperCase() + "-" + myarr[1];
});
```

Utilizando o `split` para separar os valores e o `toUpperCase` para transformar em uppercase.

Lembrando que esta solução foi feita para um único `-`

Comment: O certo não seria acessar o `array` pelo indíce `0`?  `myarr[0].toUpperCase()`. O que acontece se ele tiver multiplos traços `-`?

Comment: realmente @gabrielhof não pensei na hipótese te ter mais de um - e dos indices esta correto

Comment: Da uma olhada no que acontece: http://jsfiddle.net/qbbgx3e7/

Comment: sim @gabrielhof já editei a resposta ajustando o array e testei junto no seu fiddle deu certo

Answer (score 0):

### Resolvido

```
function beforeDash( val ){
    return val.replace(/(?:\w+-)/g, function(match){
        return match.toUpperCase()
    });
}
```